# Is Redactor's default config saved as a .json file anywhere?

Tags: config, redactor

When I need to make one tiny change to the default config it would be handy to be able to duplicate the current default.json file and just change a one thing instead of building a duplicate from scratch.

It's a small thing, but it would be a nice time saver. I've had no luck finding it, does anyone know if the default is saved somewhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Brandon said, the defaults are hardcoded in redactor.js so there isn't a default.json file, but if there was, this is what it would be (from Craft 2.3.2615):

```json
{
    buttons: ['html', 'formatting', 'bold', 'italic', 'deleted',
    'unorderedlist', 'orderedlist', 'outdent', 'indent',
    'image', 'link', 'alignment', 'horizontalrule'],

    formatting: ['p', 'blockquote', 'pre', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5']
}
```

Since the above code could change on occasion consider checking directly over at the Redactor site:

[Buttons defaults](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/buttons/#setting-buttons)

[Formatting defaults](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/formatting/#setting-formatting)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately no, the “Default” config is just whatever default values are hard-coded in redactor.js.

Comment: Too bad. That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for the confirmation though! I'll post an answer with the code for it the next time I duplicate it.